# Python: Fastest way for Mapping function to a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have the following question:

I have a matrix of distances with the shape (41, 79, 181) and 20000 iterations in which small boxes of the matrix are calculated, mostly of the shape (31,15,33).  Now I want to apply a linear function on them which converts those distances to other numbers. The calculations have to be as fast as possible. I tried two things:

1. Create the linear function and vectorize it with numpy to apply it on matrix. This seems very slow for me.
2. Using np.unique to get all different available distances and mask it on the matrix, faster for me because most of the time there are only 400-500 different distances.

**Now I would like to know if there is a faster way to do that.** In the following the code I used. First method is outcommented out because it seems slower. The second method is in this example of the same speed because i do not know how to create a 3d array with random numbers in which only 400-500 different numbers occur:

```
import numpy as np


def linearCalc(x,radius,frc_size,cellScoring,frcScoring,sH,sMin):        
    if x > radius+frc_size:
        return 0.0
    elif x<= radius:
        if cellScoring==1: 
            points = [(0,-sH),(radius,-sMin)]
            x_coords, y_coords = zip(*points)
            A = np.vstack([x_coords,np.ones(len(x_coords))]).T
            m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y_coords)[0]
            return m*x+c

vfunc = np.vectorize(linearCalc)
minX=10 
maxX=47 
minY=64
maxY= 89 
minZ= 22 
maxZ= 55                    
radius=2
fcr_size=4
cellScoring=1
frcScoring=1
sH=15
sMin=1


TemporalMatrix = np.random.rand(41, 79, 181)
    ####### 1. Method ##########
"""    
for t in range(0,20000):
    print('cell:',t)
    eucledanBox2= np.zeros(TemporalMatrix.shape)
    distanceValues = np.unique(TemporalMatrix[minX:maxX,minY:maxY,minZ:maxZ])
    eucledanBox2[minX:maxX,minY:maxY,minZ:maxZ] = vfunc(TemporalMatrix[minX:maxX,minY:maxY,minZ:maxZ],radius,fcr_size,1,1,15,1)

"""
     ####### 2. Method ##########   
for t in range(0,20000):
    print('cell:',t) 
    eucledanBox2= np.zeros(TemporalMatrix.shape)
    distanceValues = np.unique(TemporalMatrix[minX:maxX,minY:maxY,minZ:maxZ])
    for i in distanceValues:
        eucledanBox2[minX:maxX,minY:maxY,minZ:maxZ][TemporalMatrix[minX:maxX,minY:maxY,minZ:maxZ] == i] = linearCalc(i,radius,fcr_size,cellScoring,frcScoring,sH,sMin)
```

Is there a faster way? Best regards!

**EDIT**

There is to metion that the distance matrix is computed through a eucledean distance transform by scipys ndimage.distance_transform_edt. Maybe it is possible to combine it in one step with my conversion?

Comment: Please read the docs: `np.vectorize` is *not* meant for performance, it's implementation is essentially a for-loop.

Comment: yes, this is the reason i asked for ideas for faster solution :) Furthermore its commentedout, and there is another method i tried